# Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'interface'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs3, eslint

I've got a file called types.ts where I want to add some interfaces and types.

Right now all I have in this file is:

```
interface Email {
  label: string;
  text: string;
}
const mail: Email = { label: "subject", text: "mail" };
```

That's all. But the Vscode gives this error:

> Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'interface'. (1:0)eslint

How could I make this go away?

Comment: Maybe the error is caused by a previous code (some missing braces, or semicolon).

Comment: The file contains only these codes, there are nothing else in it

Comment: Are you using volar extension?

Comment: Yes, TypeScript Vue Plugin

Comment: did you have any luck with this? it is breaking my Nuxt builds. even in branches that were working a month ago.

Comment: I'm using Quasar and I've updated the Quasar config fila and the error went away.